# How to get duplicate values with different keys in One Object Javascripts?

Tags: javascript, object

I need some help to get Object keys that have duplicate values.
What i have is about 10000 keys in *Object name* **numn** (This is example)

```
numn={
    "28": "The invincible special forces who returned to the Three Kingdoms(回到三国的无敌特种兵)",
    "46": "Three Kingdoms: The opening incorporates Li Cunxiao(三国：开局融合了李存孝)",
    "62": "Douluo: Super Beast Armed Guard Zhu Zhuqing(斗罗：超兽武装守护朱竹清)",
    "76": "The Oriental Cavalry that swept across the Three Kingdoms(横扫三国的东方铁骑)",
    "1514": "The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)",
    "3140": "A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)",
    "5117": "The rise of an empire(帝国崛起)",
    "5127": "After eavesdropping on my voice, the whole family went crazy(偷听我心声后，全家都杀疯了)",
    "5148": "The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)",
    "8440": "A ghost calls at the door in the middle of the night(夜半鬼叫门)",
    "13140": "A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)",
    "13154": "The time travel story of Iron Ambition Man(钢铁雄心之舰男穿越记)",
}
```

What i want is to get all duplicate values with its keys like this

```
numn={
    "1514": "The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)",
    "5117": "The rise of an empire(帝国崛起)",
    "5148": "The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)",
    "3140": "A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)",
    "13140": "A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)",
}
```

I tried this

```
let findDuplicates = arr => arr.filter((item, index) => arr.indexOf(item) !== index)
Duplicates=findDuplicates(Object.values(numn))
```

but it only get duplicate values without it keys

```
Duplicates=[
'The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)',
'A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)'
]
```

Please help me and
Sorry for my bad writing in English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function findDuplicatesSimple(obj) {
  let duplicates = {};
  let values = Object.values(obj);
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    // Check if the value appears more than once and hasn't been added to duplicates yet
    if (
      values.filter((v) => v.toLowerCase() === obj[key].toLowerCase()).length >
      1
    ) {
      duplicates[key] = obj[key];
    }
  });
  return duplicates;
}

const numn = {
  28: "The invincible special forces who returned to the Three Kingdoms(回到三国的无敌特种兵)",
  46: "Three Kingdoms: The opening incorporates Li Cunxiao(三国：开局融合了李存孝)",
  62: "Douluo: Super Beast Armed Guard Zhu Zhuqing(斗罗：超兽武装守护朱竹清)",
  76: "The Oriental Cavalry that swept across the Three Kingdoms(横扫三国的东方铁骑)",
  1514: "The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)",
  3140: "A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)",
  5117: "The rise of an empire(帝国崛起)",
  5127: "After eavesdropping on my voice, the whole family went crazy(偷听我心声后，全家都杀疯了)",
  5148: "The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)",
  8440: "A ghost calls at the door in the middle of the night(夜半鬼叫门)",
  13140: "A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)",
  13154: "The time travel story of Iron Ambition Man(钢铁雄心之舰男穿越记)",
};

console.log(findDuplicatesSimple(numn));
```

This function iterates over the keys of your original object and filters the values directly to check if the current value exists more than once among all values (case-insensitively). If a duplicate is found and it hasn't been added to the `duplicates` object yet, it gets added. This slightly simplified approach reduces the amount of code but keeps the core logic to solve the problem effectively.

And the result is:

```
{
  '1514': 'The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)',
  '3140': 'A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)',
  '5117': 'The rise of an empire(帝国崛起)',
  '5148': 'The Rise of an Empire(帝国崛起)',
  '13140': 'A leisurely life in another world(异界的悠闲生活)'
}
```